# How to check which radiogroup button is selected?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have three radiobuttons in a radiogroup. How can I tell Java to do a different thing depending on which button is selected? I have the group and all of the buttons declared:

```
final RadioGroup size = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RGSize);
        final RadioButton small = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RBS);
        final RadioButton medium = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RBM);
        final RadioButton large = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RBL);
```

I know I would say something like this:

```
if (size.getCheckedRadioButtonId().equals(small){

} else{

}
```

But equals is not the correct syntax... How can I ask java which button is selected?

Comment: Please have a look at http://www.thetekblog.com/2010/07/android-radiobutton-in-radiogroup-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if (size.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == small.getId()){
 ....
}
else if(size.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == medium.getId()){
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns an integer, you are trying to compare an integer with RadioButton object. You should compare the id of `small`(which is `R.id.RBS`) and `getCheckedRadioButtonId()`:

```
switch(size.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
    case R.id.RBS: //your code goes here..
                    break;
    case R.id.RBM: //your code goes here..
                    break;
    case R.id.RBL: //your code goes here..
                    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int selected = size.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

switch(selected){
case R.id.RBS:
   break;
case R.id.RBM:
   break;
case R.id.RBL:
   break;

}
```